# Jmeter -- how memory-consuming is__UUID()?

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter, load, uuid

I've faced a situation when some of my tests require posting some absolutely unique data. Therefore I need to use `__UUID() function`.

I was wondering if the usage of this function can create additional load, as apart from doing what the test is supposed to do it generates the guid.

How memory-consuming is this operation, and how 'clean & objective' such a test can be considered in terms of performance analysis?

Answer (score 1):

It should be reasonable as it calls :

> UUID.randomUUID().toString()

Of course it uses a bit of memory (JMeter function system + few bytes for UUID)

It think the impact is more related to CPU.

Just monitor your JMeter JVM and check it stays in reasonable limits.